# Why do I get an ImportError when executing sys.path.append in a file but not in the Python console?

Tags: python, package

I'm trying to run a script that requires a package in another directory.

This works:

- `execfile("../test.py")` when starting python in package parent directory
- `sys.path.append("package parent")` while in the python interpreter and then calling `execfile("test.py")`

This doesn't work (gives an `ImportError`):

- `python ../test.py` when in package parent directory
- `python test.py` when in script directory

The `test.py` file contains the same `sys.path.append` instruction I used in the interpreter. Is there a difference between running it in the file or in the interpreter?

---

My directory structure:

- test.py
- package

  - stuff.py

The error message I get:

> from package.stuff import SomeClass
>   ImportError: No module named package.stuff

Answer (score 1):

A hint why the behavior from the interactive shell is different from script behavior can be found in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) for `sys.path`:

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), `path[0]` is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first. Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of `PYTHONPATH`.

This should explain why executing from an interactive shell works. However, without further information it can only be guessed why the script fails.

Setting `PYTHONPATH` is essentially the same as updating `sys.path`. On `bash` this would be:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/package1:/path/to/package2 python test.py
```

Check out [this post](http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath) and [the docs](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html) for details.

Comment: I've tried setting the PYTHONPATH and it's working now. Could you explain why appending sys.path works in one case but not in the other?

Comment: Please post the contents of `sys.path` after appending, and also the current working directory

Comment: Appending sys.path works, the entry is added correctly. However, executing the script only works in the interpreter. I've used the working directory of test.py.

Comment: Edited answer. Are you sure you update sys.path correctly? Do you insert an absolute path?

Comment: Yes, I use an absolute path. I pasted the code from the test.py into the interpreter.

Comment: Could you please add your `test.py` to the question?

Comment: It's just the sys.path.append and the import statement.

Comment: Is it? I had to add at least an `import sys` statement. That's why I'm asking for code, to be able to replicate the problem. -- But now I'm puzzled. Running as script works if there is an empty `__init__.py` in the package directory, and fails if the file is missing. Perhaps a starting point for a new question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you updated the answer. I don't really understand why the `sys.path.append` wasn't enough in one case, but a t least it's working now.